# netcat reverseshell hanging after connection

Tags: netcat

I put a reverse shell on a machine in my lab enviornment and it seems to just hang after there is a connection in netcat - I'm not sure why this is.

I've tried different ports but no luck. See screenshot below - any ideas are much appreciated

[image: using port 31337]

[image: using port 9009]

Comment: the reverse shell exits after establishing a connection.what are you using to establish the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was my choice of shell from msfvenom - I was using windows/shell/reverse_tcp but that requires a meterpreter connection , I wanted to use netcat so I needed to use windows/shell_reverse_tcp

Comment: Isnt that what i was asking you in the comments?

Comment: Yes it helped me understand what the problem was. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try using either ncat or netcat instead of nc.
Plus Ncat support -e function for executing, and i do not think that nc does in the current version.

Comment: after trying all 3 (nc , netcat , ncat) I am still getting the hanging connection